# In Git, What is the difference between "remotes/origin/HEAD" and "remotes/origin/master"

Tags: git

```
>git branch -a
* master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/master
```

Are they both same, if yes then why do we have two.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `master` is checked out, then `HEAD` is `master`. That is not the case if another branch (or simply a commit) is checked out - as HEAD is a reference to the current commit you're on.

Example:

```
git checkout wip
# Then HEAD == wip

git checkout aed24d
# Then HEAD == aed24d
```

Answer (score 0):

HEAD is a comvenience.  It's a helper/shortcut.
It's frequently pointed at origin/master but it can also point to another branches commit.